# How to paginate Django Admin for Order Model

Tags: python, django

In my E-commerce Project, Everytime I click on the orders model in Django Admin, it takes a while to load, so I thought the reason might be because of the many orders in the page which is not paginated.

So my question is how to paginate the order.model in Django Admin, second is this the reason why it is the only page that is taking a while to load or might there be another reason that I should be thinking of?

Here is the models.py

```
class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ref_code = models.CharField(max_length=20, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(OrderItem)
---------------------------------------
```

Here is the admin.py

```
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'user', 'ordered', 'ordered_date', 'coupon', 'payment', 'shipping_address', 'status',
                    'refund_requested', 'refund_granted', 'ref_code']
    list_display_links = [
        'id',
    ]
    list_editable = ['status']
    list_filter = ['ordered', 'ordered_date', 'refund_requested', 'refund_granted', 'status']
    search_fields = [
        'user__username',
        'ref_code'
    ]
    actions = [make_refund_accepted]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already pagination in default and default page size is 100

You can reduce/change it to any number e.g: 20 by **list_per_page**

```
class OrderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['id', 'user', 'ordered', 'ordered_date', 'coupon', 'payment', 'shipping_address', 'status',
                    'refund_requested', 'refund_granted', 'ref_code']
    list_display_links = [
        'id',
    ]
    list_editable = ['status']
    list_filter = ['ordered', 'ordered_date', 'refund_requested', 'refund_granted', 'status']
    search_fields = [
        'user__username',
        'ref_code'
    ]
    actions = [make_refund_accepted]
    list_per_page = 20
```